# Sending float data through serial port writing on UDR0?

Tags: floating-point, serial-port, arduino

I need to send float data through UDR0 register for my c# application. I am able to read it in my application but I couldn't send float data with UDR0 because UDR0 is a 1 byte (8bits) register and float is 4 bytes.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h> 
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h>




void setup()
{    

  #define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
  #define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)
   UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(UBRR_VALUE>>8);
   UBRR0L = (uint8_t)UBRR_VALUE;
   UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);   // Turn on the transmission, reception, and Receive interrupt 
  UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00);   
   interrupts();   
}

int c = 0;
float send_ ;



void loop()
{  

}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{ 
  cli(); 
  while(!(UCSR0A&(1<<RXC0))){};
  c= UDR0;  // clear the USART interrupt
  send_ = (c / 4);
  UDR0 = send_;
  sei();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read the 4 byte (if you send binary data, if you encoded it into a string that nimber is variable), use a union (there are others way, but union is the easyest) to convert bytes to float, divide it by 4, then send back the 4 byte.

Because it is stored in exponential format (see IEE754) you can do this just for the mantissa, but it would be extremly complicated and with marginal or no gain.

Comment: That means things are getting hot. C is okay but registerwise and portwis stuff are exhausting. I will consider your suggestion. Thanks